# getting a subimage of a CImage

Tags: c++, mfc

I've recently started learning how to use MFC in Visual Studio.  My program uses many small 32x32 pixel images that for convenience are put together in one large .png.  I've figured out how to load the big image into a CImage and display it on a CClientDC, but I can't find anything that helps me split the image into those smaller 32x32 images.

Alternatively, I can get the pixel data for the big image using DevIL, but I can't find anything that constructs a CImage from pixel data.

As I've only started learning MFC a few days ago, I don't know the API too well and I'm probably missing something obvious.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the CImage::Draw() overload that lets you specify the source rectangle.  So that you can clip the image that you want to paint from the original.  There are two candidates, the Draw(HDC hDestDC, const RECT& rectDest, const RECT& rectSrc) for example.  The other one is the first one listed on this [doc page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cz787xf9.aspx).

Comment: Ah, that did it.  Somehow I missed that overload.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you don't want to create a small image if you're just using the multi-icon image in a GUI.

When you come to draw the icon, pass its offset and size to the bitblt function rather than the dimensions of the whole image.

If you do want to store the sub-image in a bitmap, create a memory DC for the target bitmap and draw into that.

Comment: You use CBitmap::FromHandle to get a bitmap from it